# undefined var in aggregate (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use a variable within aggregate, but I get the undefined variable message:

```
var rows = [{name:'hi1'}, {name:'hi2'}];

for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
var query = Collection.aggregate([{ $match: {name: rows[i].name}}]);
query.exec((err, docs)=>{
console.log(rows[i].name)
})
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Any suggestions on how is the correct sequence?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be great if you can provide model of your Collection.

Comment: Can't see where you defined `Collection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting classical js closure error. 
It happens, because `var` is unsafe and "declared" outside of `for` loop.
You can chek it yourself:

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    console.log(i); // prints i from 0 to 9
}
console.log(i); // prints 10
```

In context of async operations the actual value if `i` is taken from memory at the time, when those operation ends. When your query finish execution - the loop is ended, therefore the actual value of `i` is equal to `-1`.

To avoid this behaviour use es6 `let` instead of `var`.
You can get more information in [this videio](https://youtu.be/sjyJBL5fkp8).

Answer (score 1):

for loop is a synchronous operation and your query is an asynchronous... So  as long as it reaches inside your callback function the `i` (`rows[i]`) becomes undefined and throws the error.

So alternate to the `for` loop is to use map function here by making it asynchronous using `async await`

```
const rows = [{ name: 'hi1' }, { name:'hi2' }]

rows.map(async(row) => {
    const query = await Collection.aggregate([
        { $match: { name: rows.name }}
    ])
    console.log(row)
    console.log(query) 
})
```